# W2UI Grid Date Formats

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I am using a plugin / framework called `W2UI` to render a grid to my page with search / sorting functionality.

Everything is working perfectly until I noticed that one of the columns are not being sorted correctly. For my dates, we use a bit of a different standard due to trying to keep it consistent across multiple regions.

Our dates are: `14 Jun 2016`.

I have the column definitions set up as follows:

```
{ name: 'field_date', type: 'date', options: { format: 'DD Mon YYYY' }}
```

As it stands, the column is still out of order when I try and sort on that column.

Are there any ways to use custom date formats like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
{ name: 'field_date', type: 'date', render: 'date:yyyy.mm.dd'}
```